# How to convert a timestamp varchar that contains a timezone to a timestamp type

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I have timestamps like the following `'2018-04-18T18:11:16+01:00'` in `varchar` type and want to transform them to a `timestamp` type. I am having trouble using the `to_timestamp()`. Is there a specific way to use the `to_timestamp()` function that will allow me to do the transformation i want? If not, is there any other way to achieve my goal?

Doing

```
to_timestamp('2018-04-18T18:11:16+01:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

gives an error  of

> Error: date/time field value out of range:
>   "2018-04-18T18:11:16+01:00"

I would expect varchars like '2018-04-18T18:11:16+01:00' to be transformed to 2018-04-18 17:11:16 (where type is timestamp)

Comment: Do you want to hold the time zone or do you want to convert into UTC (if so: cutting the +1 or calculate the UTC?)

Comment: I want to convert to UTC. Your answer below does the trick. Excellent! thanks

Comment: No, my first answer does not convert. My addition does.

Comment: Seems like your first answer converts to UTC and the type of the field is timestamp with timezone. I ran `select '2018-04-18T18:11:16+01:00'::timestamptz, pg_typeof('2018-04-18T18:11:16+01:00'::timestamptz);` and got `2018-04-18 17:11:16.000000, timestamp with time zone`
Your last one indeed converts to UTC with the field's type being timestamp without timezone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=eb9fd63dfa36064438c18b7783a1a0eb)

---

If you simply want to get the string into a timestamp holding the time zone:

Simply cast it into `timestamp with time zone` (= `timestamptz`) type:

```
SELECT '2018-04-18T18:11:16+01:00'::timestamptz
```

---

If you just want to cut the time zone part and holding the time without any further calculations: Simply cast it into type `timestamp without time zone` (= `timestamp`)

```
SELECT '2018-04-18T18:11:16+01:00'::timestamp
```

---

If you want to convert it into a timestamp at UTC (calculating -1) you can do:

```
SELECT ('2018-04-18T18:11:16+01:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::timestamp
```